# Javascript manifest file "application.js" is not processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am on a Macbook Pro and I created a new Rails 3.2 app, but the assets pipeline does not work. Here is what I did:

```
$ rails version
  Rails 3.2.5
$ rails new test_assets
$ cd test_assets
$ rails server
```

The server is started OK, but if I visit `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/application.js`, it turns out the manifest file is not processed at all, it shows:

```
//... some comments ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
;
```

I tried to do the exactly the same steps on my other Macbook Pro. It works well. Visiting `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/application.js` on that machine shows a compiled javascript file with all the contents.

I have read http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, and I searched for hours on the web but with no clue.

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue!

Downgrading Ruby from 2.0.0 to 1.9.3 fixed the issue

Comment: This also worked for me.  Something is seriously wrong with the framework when all we have to go on with debugging is a single semi-colon.

Comment: Sorry for accepting late. I could not remember the details, but it was a ruby version issue at that time.

Comment: My app is created in Rails 5, the minimum supported version is Ruby 2.2 and I don't know how to fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions: install node.js or uncomment `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` in your Gemfile

I followed the same steps and my log file looks like this... What does yours look like if you start the server and request /assets/application.js? As you can see, I'm on 3.2.6, and it compiled my application.js

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-07-19 22:50:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-07-19 22:50:02] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
[2012-07-19 22:50:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=21393 port=3000


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-19 22:50:13 -0500
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Served asset /rails.png - 200 OK (9ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-19 22:50:23 -0500
Compiled jquery.js  (2ms)  (pid 21393)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 21393)
Compiled application.js  (26ms)  (pid 21393)
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (74ms)
[2012-07-19 22:50:24] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: `Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-20 12:42:00 +0800
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Compiled application.js  (0ms)  (pid 26678)
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (20ms)`

Comment: Above is my console message (sorry I did not know how to format it in a comment).  And, neither installing node.js nor uncomment `therubyracer` helps.

Comment: years and years later, trying to figure out why the Rails 5 precompile step worked with a development RAILS_ENV but not with production, this answer gave me the idea to remove the old therubyracer gem in the Gemfile and everything works again! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Faced exactly the same case.

I've found that I use ruby like v2.0.0rc or something like that, and all works perfect if I downgrade it to 1.9.3p194 (both are under the Rbenv).

Though you can use helper in a view, like `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>`, it also helped me even with ruby2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue today and I was ready to downgrade Ruby to 1.9.3 from 2.0 to solve the issue of application.js not compiling. The issue happened on the production server, which has Ruby 2.0 installed (and Rails 3.2.8). On the development machine(Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8) application.js compiled just fine.

At last resort, I upgraded the production server from Rails 3.2.8 to 3.2.14; remove Gemfile.lock, and ran bundle install. Then I recompiled the assets, and voila application.js compiled the assets.

I thought of sharing this with Stackoverflow audience, maybe this will solve someone else's issues.

Answer (score 0):

The first officially supported version of rails 3.2 with ruby 2.0 is 3.2.13.So upgrade your rails version to rails 3.2.13 will solve the problem.

> Step for upgrading:
>
> 1)Change rails version in Gemfile to gem 'rails', '3.2.22'.
>
> 2)bundle update rails

Answer (score -1):

On development the assets are not precompiled. If you want to see them, you should run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: I think you meant `rake assets:precompile`. No, that does not work.  I think it only applies to production environment. Note that the exactly same steps work on my another machine.

Comment: Nope I meant the one with `bundle`. You can run that in development too. Anyway, have you checked under `your_app/public/assets` ?

Comment: It says `Could not find task "rake"`. But I can run it with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.  With no luck either. There are some files generated under `public/assets` after this command, like `application-xxx.js` and `application.js`, but this does not solve the problem.  By the way, on my other machine, it works, but without a folder named `public/assets`.

Answer (score -3):

open enviornment/development.rb and set config.assets.debug = false . That's it

Comment: Doing this I go from `<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>` to `<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` It doesn't help me at all since no matter what the application.js file is still not processed.