# Javascript files are not included from manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, manifest, precompile

I am using Ruby On Rails and have ActiveAdmin on top of that on a windows machine. I don´t think ActiveAdmin has anything to do with it, but I am just saying.

The Javascript file that is included via HTML is `/assets/active_admin.js` and the manifest file itself looks like this:

```
//= require active_admin/base

//= require just_datetime_picker/nested_form_workaround
```

When I run my Rails application and open `http://localhost:3000/assets/active_admin.js`, the log tells me, that `active_admin.js` was compiled, but the file still looks just like the manifest just with an added semicolon at the end:

```
//= require active_admin/base

//= require just_datetime_picker/nested_form_workaround
;
```

**Why is no Javascript code included?**

When I try to run the precompile pipeline manually via `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development`, it actually creates all the CSS files, but the JS files still look like the one described above.

Since I am operating on a windows machine, I do not have the gem 'therubyracer' installed, but NodeJS. Also the `bundle install` works fine and I also do not get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ruby v2.0?  Try downgrading to 1.9.

**Symptom:** *The JavaScript manifest file does not compile, no errors are shown; however, a mysterious semi-colon `;` appears at the end of the file after "preprocessing" the assets.*

**Solution:** *Downgrade to Ruby v1.9.3!*

See two other posts on the same topic.

- [My Rails Javascript manifest file neither compiles nor include any required files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811889/my-rails-javascript-manifest-file-doesnt-compile-nor-include-any-required-files)
- [Javascript manifest file "application.js" is not processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571605/javascript-manifest-file-application-js-is-not-processed)

What a sorry mess it is to be programming in 2013!

Comment: The problem is that Rails 5 supports only Ruby >= 2.2